# Angular update position in realtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do a scroll detection that will update the position of an element on scrolling.

JS code:

```
angular.directive('menu', ['$window', function($window){
    return function (scope, element) {
        var w = angular.element($window);
        var top = element.offset().top;

        w.bind('scroll', function () {
            adjustHeight();
        });

        function adjustHeight(){
            var newtop = top - w.scrollTop();
            if(newtop>0){
                scope.top = top - w.scrollTop();
            }else{
                scope.top = '0';
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-style="{'top':top}" menu></div>
```

The position is get updated only after scrolling is stopped. How can I get the real time position update?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Angualar about your changes so it can apply it:

```
w.bind('scroll', function () {
    adjustHeight();
    scope.$apply();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the adjustheight event handler runs outside of angular scope. It's advisable to use scope.$apply for it.

Also it's better to assign `w.scrollTop();`  to a variable to improve performance.

```
angular.directive('menu', ['$window', function($window){
    return function (scope, element) {
        var w = angular.element($window);
        var top = element.offset().top;

        w.bind('scroll', function () {
            scope.$apply(adjustHeight); // pass the adjustheight function to scope.$apply.

        });

        function adjustHeight(){
            var scrolltop = w.scrollTop();
            var newtop = top - scrolltop;
            if(newtop>0){
                scope.top = top - scrolltop;
            }else{
                scope.top = '0';
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```